# Read, Display and Insert into another Table

Tags: mysql, node.js, optimization

I am new to NodeJS programming, 
Have created a script which reads from Database table **nodetest** having 50K records and displays in the browser and then writes to another table called **'nodetestcopy'**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var connection = require('express-myconnection');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var rows={};

var copyOfrows={
    'id':null,
    'f_name':null,
    'l_name':null,
    'title':null
};
var date1 = (new Date()).getTime();
app.use(
      connection(mysql,{
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : '',
        port : null, //port mysql
        database:'test'
    },'request')
);



app.get('/api/entries', function(req, res){
req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send('Cannot get database connection');
    } else {
        connection.query("select * from nodetest", function(err, rows) {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
          } else {
            res.write(''+JSON.stringify(rows));
            var date2 = (new Date()).getTime();
            console.log('Cnt : '+rows.length+' Took Time to execute :'+(date2 - date1)/(60*60));
            //console.log(rows);
            //Now insert in another table ' nodetestcopy'
            for(var i in rows){
                connection.query("insert into nodetestcopy set ?", rows[i], function(err, rows) {
                  if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    //res.status(500).send(err);
                  } else {

                  }
      });
            }

          }
      });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This script is working for the first time, and when I refresh the browser for second time, getting an error .

Please guide me what is going wrong here and also Is my approach is correct?
Looping the record for 50K times *for(var i in rows){ ...}*

Please give a feasible solution for this, and correct me wereever the code is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message that you are getting? Also, another way to avoid hitting the database with multiple queries could be to combine the records in one query and then make one database insert call, like:

```
var query = 'insert into nodetestcopy values("';
for (var i in rows) {
     query += rows[i] + '"';
     if (i < rows.length) query += ',';
}
query += ')';

connection.query(query, function(err, rows) { ...
```